# Possible to use output of one cell as input to another?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'd like to take the output from one cell (probably a code cell) and use it as input to the next code cell.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible! Simply store the output from your first cell into a variable and then use the variable as the input in your second cell. Hopefully, that helps, let me know if you need more clarification!

Comment: Yes, this might work perfectly.  Can you tell me how you would "store the output from your first cell into a variable?"

Comment: @FrankMiller Assuming you are working int python, let's say in cell number 1 you had print("hello").  simply change that to declare a variable named statement. and then change your code to statement = print("hello") and then in cell number 2 use statement as your input. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're looking for this :

In: `x = 5`

In: `x`

Out : `5`

and now if you want to use this output as input, do this:

In : `_ + 6`

Out : `11`

Let's use it Again:

In : `_*5`

Out : `55`

and so on and on.
I guess this is equivalent to using `%` in Mathematica.